# Custom image like button on facebook doesn't work

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-like

When I want to share a site on facebook and want to add a custom image it doesn't work. It always gives the same image (one that is somewhere on the web page).

This is the code I've used:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.the-website.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://url-to-image.com" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The content" />

</head>
<body>
<h1> Facebook Like </h1>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.the-website.com%2F&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried running the page through Facebook linter - http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/ - it may show up some issue.

Comment: can you post this as an answer so I can accept it? This solved up the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try running the page through Facebook linter - http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/ - it may show up some issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read it ? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
There is a "code generator" which would do all coding for you. Try it, then copy&paste the code...

As for your code:
- in this case - to have a like on a page - there is no meta needed (your example's meta are not needed).
- you have probably something wrong inside src tag: my guess is to REMOVE the "font&" part, but this might be wrong...

In any case... just use the link I provided...

Comment: Both codes (iFrame and the meta tags) are created by that site, that's why i find it that weird

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I did was, I just removed the entire line " `<meta property="og:image" content="xxxxxxx" />` " . This will push the facebook crawler to scan for every images in the page. Now place the image you want to add somewhere in the page with width=1 and height=1. Users won't recognise this in your page. But this image will be scanned by the crawler and you can select it to show it on our page. This worked for me. I don't know whether it will work for you or not.

NB: This is just a workaround, not a good solution